# OpenMP barrier implementation on MacOS

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, barrier

I have been playing around with openmp and have used barrier construct to execute a simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int x[100];
  int tid;
  int y[100];
  int z[100];
  for(i=0;i<10;i++) x[i]==i;

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    y[tid]==x[tid]*2;
    printf("%d\n",tid);
    #pragma omp barrier
    printf("After Barrier%d\n",tid);
  }
}
```

---

I have executed this code on MacOS and got a result like this:
[The output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDQyA.png)

In the output till the barrier the 4 threads were executed but after the barrier only one thread is being executed 4 times but according to barrier after barrier also 4 different threads should perform the step . Can anyone help me solve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can reproduce your result. It appears to choose a random tread after the barrier. So it either prints all 2 or all 7. Strange.

Comment: Race condition on `tid`. That's it. Use `#pragma omp parallel private(tid)` or declare `tid` inside the parallel region`

Comment: Z boson thanks alot  .Race condition was the issue . I used private clause and it worked.